# Men of war Assault Squad 2 tag

Tags: support, tags

We need a Men Of War: Assault Squad 2 tag. It could be MOW:AS2 or MOWAS2

Comment: Have you asked a question about it?

Comment: @Frank http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/262771/gem-editor-how-do-i-make-that-if-something-dies-the-mission-is-failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retagged to [men-of-war-as2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/men-of-war-as2)

[men-of-war-assault-squad-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/men-of-war-assault-squad-2) was 1 character too long for the limit, and a quick search on Google showed usage for [men-of-war-as2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/men-of-war-as2)